# Storybook addon-docs in Typescript strange behaviour

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, storybook

I want to use storybook addon-docs with my typescript react project. I almost have it working but the file name seems to be affecting the rendered props type table.

file structure:

```
src
- Button
-- Button.tsx
- stories
-- Button.stories.tsx
```

This kind of works but the descriptions are generic such as:
`union` rather than `'small' | 'medium' | 'large'`

But when I change it to:

```
src
- Button
-- Button.stories.tsx
- stories
-- Button.stories.tsx
```

it works exactly as expected. Very strange. 
I will provide my files below:

#### Button.tsx

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from "react";

type ButtonProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  onClick?: () => void;
  size?: 'tiny' | 'small' | 'regular';
};

/**
 * The world's most _basic_ button
 */
export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick} type="button">
    {props.children}
  </button>
);
```

#### Button.stories.tsx

```
import { Button } from '../Button/Button.stories';
import React from 'react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button,
};

export const Text = () => <Button onClick={action('clicked')}>Hello Button</Button>;
```

#### .storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mdx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-docs",
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "cra-ts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
    "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.7.2",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from "react";

export type ButtonProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  onClick?: () => void;
  size?: 'tiny' | 'small' | 'regular';
};

/**
 * The world's most _basic_ button
 */
const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick} type="button">
    {props.children}
  </button>
);

export default Button;
```

Exporting the component on a new line worked!